# bash: create-react-app: command not found (pretty sure it's my $PATH)

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, reactjs, path

Let me preface by stating that this is my first post, and also I can’t retrace my steps to where the `create-react-app` command no longer works in my Terminal. Last week, when I was practicing how to work with `ReactJS` I was able to use the command create-react-app and had been able to initialize a React project. However, I’ve been  fiddling plentifully with `NodeJS` and `NPM` stuff simultaneously, and now when I call the  create react-app command this is the output:

`bash: create-react-app: command not found`

I’m pretty sure it has to do with my `$PATH`, however I’m not experienced with making edits through vim 
when editing my `.bash_profile`. In my attempts to diagnose and fix the problem, here is what I appended to my $PATH through vim:

`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`

Nevertheless, I know the order of $PATH matters, but I’m naive as to whether I should prepend or append the $PATH above?

Here is what is output when I echo $PATH:

> /usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/Users/bjornjohnramos/.rbenv/bin:/Users/bjornjohnramos/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/bjornjohnramos/.npm-packages/bin/express
>   -> /Users/bjornjohnramos/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express-cli.js:/Users/bjornjohnramos/.npm-packages/lib:export
>   PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH":export
>   PATH=$PATH:/Users/my_name/.npm-packages/bin/

my node and npm versions:

node v6.9.1
npm 4.2.0

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Okay, I'm naive with how this site systematically functions. I'll check out the other forums, apologies I've seen similar questions concerning ReactJS and Node on here before and thought it would be a fitting topic for Stack Overflow. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Don't sweat it. I think its better to point you in the right direction rather than pound you with negative reinforcement like down votes. Those other Stack Exchange sites are great resources. I use [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Who knows what happened? But maybe we can just fix it by reinstalling...

```
npm uninstall create-react-app
npm uninstall create-react-app -g
npm install create-react-app -g
```

The first two commands will uninstall create-react-app locally and globally. (Not sure how you may have installed it. Harmless to run both.) The third installs globally, and should set up the path for you as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I reinstalled by following the instructions above and everything worked fine. However, when I attempt to run: create-react-app myRouter, I still receive the following output: -bash: create-react-app: command not found

Answer (score 0):

use command `npx create-react-app my-app`  rather than using `npx create-react-app my-app` that will resolves your **bash: create-react-app: command not found err** on windows.

Hope this is helpful
Happy coding...